# sp.ui.rte.js is not working in Internet Explorer 11 Version

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-editor-web-part

We implemented custom `Content Editor Web Part`, inside that we are using the `sp.ui.rte.js` file. It is working fine up to IE10. Our project users upgraded from IE10 to IE11. When we edit the content editor web part we are getting below error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'classname' of undefined or null
>   reference File: sp.ui.rte.js, Line: 2, Column:35101

Please let us know what is cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with different option to resolve the CEWP issues. Modified existing `SP.UI.RTE.js` file with some change as below.

```
RTE.Canvas.$1P = function (b) { if (b == undefined) return;
```

And replaced `SP.UI.RTE.js` name with `TempRte.js` and added this file in Project js folder and also referred the file in the `“XXXX.master”` file at the end.

```
<script src="../../_Layouts/xxxxx/js/TempRte.js"></script>
```

Now it is working fine. But this is temporary solution. Once Microsoft will provide patch for that we need to remove or comment the script file from Master page.

> **Note**: Do not remove or change existing “SP.UI.RTE.js” file.